# Why does the largest $x$ such that $a$, $b$ divided by $x$ leave the same remainder equal $a-b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, euclidean-algorithm, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose two numbers $a$ and $b$ as, $a=kq_1+r_1=3\times 17 + 1  = 52$ and $b = kq_2+r_2=3 \times 15 +1=46$.

It is clear that $52$ and $46$ leave the same reminder 1 when divided by $3$, because I designed them this way. But surprisingly however I design the numbers the largest $x$ which leaves the same reminder is $kq_1-kq_2=k(q_1-q_2)$. Why is that? In this case we have $52 = 6\times 8+ \color \red  4$ and $46 = 6\times 7 + \color \red 4$.

Now suppose there are three numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $x$(assuming $a>b>c \geq x$) such that $x$ leaves the same reminder when we divide each of $a,b$ and $c$ with it. $x$ is supposed to be the largest possible value that holds the assertion.  Now $x$ is given by the H.C.F of $a-b, a-c$ and $b-c$. Why is that? How can we prove this mathematically?

Comment: In your second paragraph, $x$ is the **largest** integer that leaves the same remainder.  Is the same supposed to be true in your third paragraph?  A number of people posting answers have assumed that $x$ is a given number in the third paragraph, not the largest integer for which the statement holds.  In my answer, I assumed the that it was meant to be the largest such integer, although that is not what you say.  If my reading is the intended one, then you need to correct both the third paragraph and the title of the post.  Also, you cannot assume that $x$ will be less than $c$.

Comment: @WillOrrick Yes, the $x$ in the last paragraph is supposed to be the largest possible value. This question arose when I read an exercise in my book. The exercise is to find the largest number which divides $62, 132$ and $237$ to leave the same remainder in each case. They solved it by finding the H.C.F of $(132-62), (237-132)$ and $(237-62)$. Give me some time to see the answers to see where did I go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for editing the post.  I still have a question however.  You write $a>b>c>x$.  Do you really mean to require that $x<c$?  If so, then your claim is false, as a couple of posters have pointed out.  Here's an example that shows the claim is false even for two numbers, $a$, $b$: let $a=105$, $b=9$.  If $x$ is allowed to be greater than $9$, then $x=96=105-9$, and the remainder is $9$ for both $105$ and $9$.  If $x$ must be less than $b$, then $x=6$, which is obviously not equal to $a-b$.  The remainder in this case is $3$.

Comment: Yes, $x$ is supposed to be less than $c$, otherwise we cannot divide $c$ by $x$. I guess the formula applies only when $a-b<b$.

Comment: The integer quotient of $3$ by $96$ is $0$, with a remainder $3$.  (Because $3=0\cdot96+3$.)  Unless there is a compelling reason not to allow the quotient to be $0$, it simplifies the analysis considerably to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a step-by-step answer that does not use the notion of modular arithmetic.

> Suppose two numbers $a$ and $b$ as, $a=kq_1+r_1=3\times 17 + 1  = 52$ and $b = kq_2+r_2=3 \times 15 +1=46$.
>
> It is clear that $52$ and $46$ leave the same reminder 1 when divided by $3$, because I designed them this way. But surprisingly however I design the numbers the largest $x$ which leaves the same reminder is $kq_1-kq_2=k(q_1-q_2)$. Why is that? In this case we have $52 = 6\times 8+ \color \red  4$ and $46 = 6\times 7 + \color \red 4$.

Let $a$ and $x$ be positive integers.  The **integer quotient** of $a$ and $x$ is the largest integer $q$ such that $qx\le a$.  The **remainder of $a$ on division by $x$** is $r=a-qx$; it necessarily satisfies $0\le r<x$.

Observe first that $kq_1-kq_2=(a-r)-(b-r)=a-b$, where $r$ is the common remainder of $a$ and $b$ on division by $k$.  So your statement could be rephrased as "the largest $x$ that leaves the same remainder is $a-b$."  We prove this.

Let $a>b$, and $x$ be positive integers.  Let $q_a$ and $q_b$ be the corresponding integer quotients and let $r_a$ and $r_b$ be the corresponding remainders on division by $x$.

For $a$ and $b$ to have the same remainder on division by $x$ means $r_a=r_b$ which means that $a-q_ax=b-q_bx$.  This implies that $a-b=x(q_a-q_b)$.  So if $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder on division by $x$, then $a-b$ is an integer multiple of $x$.

Conversely, if $a-b$ is an integer multiple of $x$, then $a-b=qx$ and therefore $a=b+qx$ for some integer $q$.  Since $r_a=a-q_ax$ and $r_b=b-q_bx$, we have
$$
r_a=b+qx-q_ax=r_b+q_bx+qx-q_ax=r_b+(q_b+q-q_a)x.
$$
We claim that $q_b+q-q_a=0$, and therefore $r_a=r_b$.  This follows since $0\le r_a,r_b<x$, so $-x<r_a-r_b<x$.  The only integer multiple of $x$ in this range is $0\cdot x$.  We have shown that if $a-b$ is a multiple of $x$, then $r_a=r_b$.

So $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder on division by $x$ if and only if $a-b$ is divisible by $x$.  The largest $x$ such that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder on division by $x$ must therefore be the largest integer that divides $a-b$.  This is $a-b$ itself.

> Now suppose there are three numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $x$(assuming $a>b>c>x$) such that $x$ leaves the same reminder when we divide each of $a,b$ and $c$ with it. Now $x$ is given by the H.C.F of $a-b, a-c$ and $b-c$. Why is that? How can we prove this mathematically?

We build on the previous proof to prove this one.  Any two of $a$, $b$, $c$ have the same remainder on division by $x$ if and only if their difference is divisible by $x$.  So $a$, $b$, and $c$ all have the same remainder on division by $x$ if and only if all of the differences, $a-b$, $a-c$, and $b-c$ are divisible by $x$.  The largest $x$ such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ all have the same remainder on division by $x$ is therefore the largest $x$ such that $x$ divides all three of $a-b$, $a-c$, and $b-c$.  By definition of *greatest common factor*, this is the greatest common factor of $a-b$, $a-c$, and $b-c$.

Comment: How can we prove that there always exist $q$, $q_a$ and $q_b$ which satisfie $q_b+q−q_a=0$ for every possible case?

Comment: $q$ exists because, in the paragraph of the argument you are referring to, $a-b$ is assumed divisible by $x$: $q$ is just what you get by dividing $a-b$ by $x$.  The integer quotients $q_a$ and $q_b$ exist for any positive $a$, $b$, $x$.  (Is this the part you need a proof of?)  That $q_b+q-q_a=0$ is proved in that same paragraph.  (See the sentence "This follows since...".)  If the argument is too compressed or cryptic, I can expand.  Please let me know which part is unclear.

Comment: Perhaps I got it. It follows from Euclid's algorithm. Let $a-b=x$ and $a=q_1x+r_1$ and $b=q_2x+r_2$. Which gives $a-b=\delta q x+ \delta r$. Or $x= \delta q x + \delta r \implies x(1- \delta q)= \delta r$ Now since $r_1, r_2 < x$ this implies $r_1-r_2<x$ or $\delta r < x$, which leaves $\delta q =0$ as the only possibility. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've found that the largest integer $x$ such that $a\equiv b\bmod x$ is $x=a-b$ (having assumed, WLOG, that $a\geq b$). That's because, by definition,
$$a\equiv b\bmod x\iff x\mid a-b$$
and the largest divisor of any integer is itself.

Comment: That's the definition of equivalence modulo $x$. But when we're speaking about a remainder operation, the fact that $$ (a\bmod x)=(b\bmod x) \iff x \mid a-b $$ is not just "by definition".

Comment: $ x\mid a-b \nRightarrow x=a-b$ For the greatest number $x_0$ which satisfies $a=x_0q_1+r_1$ and $b=x_0q_2+r_1$, $a-b=x_0(q_1-q_2) \implies x_0 = \dfrac{a-b}{q_1-q_2}$. Now $x=a-b$ _iff_ $q_1-q_2=1$ which is not necessary.

Comment: $max\{x\ :\ a\equiv b\mod\ x\}=max\{x\ :\ x|a-b\}=a-b$

Comment: @user103816  Of course $a-b$ is not always the _only_ integer that divides $a-b$ (for arbitrary $a$ and $b$), but it _is_ the largest. When you also require $c$ to have the same remainder as $a$ and $b$ when divided by $x$, you introduce additional conditions $x \mid a-c$ and $x \mid b-c$, which lead to taking the greatest common divisor of $a-b$, $a-c$, and $b-c.$

Comment: @DavidK $a-b$ might be the largest integer that divides $a-b$ but it doesn't prove that $x=a-b$. Moreover it is also not obvious that $a-b$ is greatest integer that divides $a$ and $b$ leaving the same reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a=k\alpha + r_1$ and $b=k\beta + r_1$,with $a\gt b$, so we have $x=a-b=k(\alpha-\beta)$, which is the distance between the two numbers. It is obvious the there cannot be a $y\gt x$ with your property, as either $y$ would surround both $a$ and $b$ or one end of the $y$ interval would be between $a$ and $b$, but equality of remainder would only occur if $y=x$.

So a distance $y$ not $x$ must be $\lt x$, and as $y=1$ gives a remainder $0$ which must be less than or equal to the original remainder, we have $1\lt y\lt x$.

Next we can prove that $gcd(x,y)\gt1$, as if not and $tgcd(x,y)=1$ , the remainder of $b$, $b\mod y$ is clearly different to $a \mod y$. If they were the same we would have $a-b\equiv 0\mod y$ and so $y|(a-b) \to y|x$, a contradiction.

But it is impossible for such a $y$ to give a remainder larger than $x$, as if $ky=x$ say, and we had $b\equiv c \mod x$, then $b\equiv (c-jy) \mod (x+jy)$ for as long as $c-jy$ is positive (i.e. $x+jy\le b$), and so is a smaller residue.

The case for three and more numbers in an arithmetic progression can be seen from seeing that in each cased the maximal $x$ be a factor of each of $a-b$, $a-c$ and $b-c$, and so must the highest common factor. This needs the additional proof that if $gcd(m,n)\gt1$ and $m\lt n$ then $remainder(m)\le remainder(n)$, which is essentially the same proof as in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the alternative. Suppose $a > b$ and $a \equiv b \mod x$ with $x > (a-b)$. That suggests that $(a - b) \equiv 0 \mod x$, which is to say that $x \mid (a - b)$. But if $x > (a - b)$, that's impossible.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the `mod` notation. Could you explain in some other way?

Comment: @user103816 $a \equiv b \mod x$ means that the remainders of $a$ and $b$ are the same when dividing by $x$. See [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: How does $x>(a−b)$ imply $(a−b)≡0\ \text{mod}\ x$? And what if $x<a-b$?

Comment: @user103816 It doesn't. You were asking if it's possible for both $x > (a-b)$ and $a \equiv b \mod x$ to be true, so I started with both assumptions.

Comment: No, I know that. I never asked that. I am asking why is (a-b) the greatest divisor that leaves the same reminder when we divide a and b by it.

Answer (score 0):

Your claim is not correct. Let $a=13$, $b=7$, $c=1$, $x=2$.

Clearly, $a=b=c = 1 \mod x$. So your assumptions are met.

Then
$$ a-b = 13-7 = 6$$
$$ b-c = 7-1 = 6 $$
$$ a-c = 13-1 = 12.$$

Obviously, $\mathrm{gcd}(6,6,12) = 6 \neq 2 = x$.

This leads to a contradiction, and hence your statement is not correct.

Comment: No, $c$ must be greater than $x$. E.g. try with, $a=13,\ b=7$ and $c=3$.

Comment: OK, how about $a=13$, $b=9$, $c=5$, $x=2$?

$a=b=c=1 \mod x$. And $\mathrm{gcd}(4,4,8) = 4 \neq 2 = x$.

Comment: I think you may be misreading the claim.  The original post does not say that if $x$ is an integer such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ all have the same remainder on division by $x$, then $x$ is the greatest common fact of $a-b$, $a-c$ and $b-c$ .  What it's saying is that if $x$ is the **largest** integer such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ all have the same remainder, then the statement is true.  Indeed, in your second example, all three of $a$, $b$, $c$ leave remainder $1$ on division by $4$; for no larger number do they leave the same remainder.

Comment: Update: please see the discussion in the comments to Michael Burr's answer.  You and he had a different reading of the question than I had, and I now see that the two of you may be right.  It's still possible that my reading is the intended one, however.  I have asked the original poster for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your claim is incorrect.  The best you can say is that if three numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ have the same remainder by division by $x$, then their differences are *multiples* of $x$, not equal to $x$.

There are many examples that show this, for example, when $a=15$, $b=9$, $c=3$ and $x=2$, then $a$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $2$, $b$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $2$, and $c$ has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $2$.  Their differences, however are $15-9=6$, $9-3=6$, and $15-3=12$, all of which are divisible by $6$, which is only a multiple of $2$, not equal to $2$.

One can prove the following claim: Suppose that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $x$.  Then $x$ divides $a-b$.

Proof: Suppose that the remainder of $a$ divided by $x$ is $r$.  Then $a=q_1x+r$.  By assumption $b$ has the same remainder, so $b=q_2x+r$.  Then $a-b=(q_1-q_2)x$, which is an integer times $x$, so the difference is a multiple of $x$, but not necessarily equal to $x$ (when $q_1-q_2\not=1$).

A corollary of this is that the HCF of $a-b$, $a-c$, and $b-c$ will be divisible by $x$, but still may be not equal to $x$, unless you choose the values in a lucky way.  The problem with the example above is that for $a$, $b$, and $c$, $q_a-q_b$, $q_a-q_c$, and $q_b-q_c$ are all divisible by $3$.

Comment: I'm not sure which claim you are saying is incorrect.  As I understood it, the claim was that the largest $x$ such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ have the same remainder on division by $x$ is the greatest common factor of $a-b$, $a-c$, and $b-c$.  This is true in your example: the greatest common factor of $15-9$, $15-3$, and $9-3$ is $6$.  Indeed $15$, $9$, and $3$ all have the same remainder, $3$, on division by $6$.  There can be no larger such integer: $3$ leaves remainder $3$ for any larger integer, while $9$ leaves remainder $2$, $1$, $0$, or $9$ for ...

Comment: ... any larger integer.  So $3$ and $9$ will leave different remainders when divided by a number larger than $6$.

Comment: @WillOrrick The OP seems to be stating the following claim: Let $x<c<b<a$ be integers such that $a\equiv b\equiv c\pmod x$.  Then $\gcd(a-b,a-c,b-c)=x$.  The way the statement is written is that the hypothesis is that $a,b,c,x$ are all chosen initially.

Comment: @WillOrrick The converse statement, let $x=\gcd(a-b,a-c,b-c)$, then $a\equiv b\equiv c\pmod x$ is a true statement.

Comment: I've reread the third paragraph of the original question more carefully, and I now see where you're coming from. The title of the post is also consistent with your reading. However, I'm pretty sure the original poster meant to ask a question parallel to the one in the second paragraph, where $x$ is not a given integer, but rather is the largest integer with the stated property. I've left a comment for the original poster requesting clarification on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the first question:

we have $a = k q_{1} + r$ and $ b = k q_{2} + r$. (Where $a >b$, $r < k$)

We deduce that $a - k q_{1} = b- k q_{2}$.

and then,

$$k = \frac{a - b}{q_{1} - q_{2}}$$

The highest value of $k$ is when $q_{1} - q_{2} = 1$.

Let prove that it is always possible.

- Suppose that $k = a - b$

we have $a = (a - b) q_{1} + r_{1}$ and $b = (a - b) q_{2} + r_{2}$

suppose that: $r_{1} = r_{2}$

Then: $(a - b) = (a - b) (q_{1} - q_{2})$

We get: $q_{1} - q_{2} = 1$

Now let suppose that $q_{1} - q_{2} = 1$

similarly we get $r_{1} = r_{2}$

So we have just proved that:

\begin{align}
 (k = a - b) \Rightarrow ( (r_{1} = r_{2}) \Leftrightarrow  (q_{1} - q_{2} = 1))
\end{align}

Now, let suppose that $k = a - b$, $r_{1} \neq r_{2}$ and $q_{1} - q_{2} \neq 1$

We get

\begin{align}
a - b = \frac{r_{1} - r_{2}}{1 - q_{1} + q_{2}}
\end{align}

It is clear from this last formulae that:

\begin{align}
r_{1} \geq (a-b) \ \ \ \ \text {or } \ \ \ \ r_{2} \geq (a-b)
\end{align}

which is a contradiction.

This means that:

\begin{align}
 (k = a - b) \Rightarrow ( (r_{1} = r_{2}) \ \ \ and  \ \ \  (q_{1} - q_{2} = 1))
\end{align}

Comment: How can we assume in the second paragraph that $(a-b)$ leaves the same remainder when it divides $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @user103816 I've updated my answer

Comment: How can you assume that for $k=a-b$,  $r_1=r_2$?

Comment: Why couldn't I suppose that ? I assumed that to prove the implication below

Comment: If you suppose $r_1=r_2$ for $k=a-b$ then there is nothing left to prove because you have assumed that $a-b$ leaves the same reminder $r$ when it divides $a$ and $b$. We also know that every possible solution of  $k$ is of type $kN=a-b$ and obviously this leaves $a-b$ as the biggest possible value of $k$. But this is the fact which we have to prove we can't just presume it.

Comment: I supposed that $r_1 = r_2$ to prove that $q_1 - q_2 = 1$ in this case. Follow the demo.

Comment: You simply can't do that. You have to prove that for every possible values of $a$ and $b$ there exist at least one pair of $(r_1,r_2)$ such that $r_1=r_2$. In other words you have to prove, $ ∀ a,b \in N\  \text{s.t}\ a>b\ \exists r_1,r_2: r_1=r_2$

Answer (score 0):

From the comments from the OP, it appears that the question is the following:

Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be integers.  Let $x=\gcd(\{a_i-a_j\}_{i,j})=\gcd(\{a_i-a_{i+1}\}_i)$ (the gcd is the same as the hcf).  Then $x$ is the largest integer $y$ such that $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod y$ (i.e., have the same remainder) for all $i$ and $j$.

This is a true statement and here's the proof.

Let us first consider the equality of the gcds.  Suppose $i<j$, then $a_i-a_j=(a_i-a_{i+1})+(a_{i+1}-a_{i+2})+\cdots+(a_{j-1}-a_j)$, so any common divisor of the $(a_i-a_{i+1})$'s is also a common divisor of the $a_i-a_j$.

Suppose that $z$ is an integer such that all $a_i$'s have the same remainder $r$.  Then $a_i=q_iz+r$ for all $i$.  In this case, $a_i-a_j=(q_i-q_j)z$, so $z$ is a common divisor of all $a_i-a_j$.

On the other hand, since $x$ is a divisor of $a_i-a_{i+1}$, $a_i-a_{i+1}=qx$ for some integer $q$.  Let $r_i$ be the remainder for $a_i$ under division by $x$, then $a_i=q_ix+r_i$.  Since $a_{i+1}=a_i-qx=(q_i-q)x+r_i$, the remainder of $a_{i+1}$ under division by $x$ is the same as the remainder as the division of $q_i$ by $x$.  Therefore, $x$ satisfies the desired properties.

In conclusion, since every integer which satisfies the desired properties (i.e., that the $a_i$'s all give the same remainder) must divide $x$ and since $x$ also satisfies the properties, $x$ is the largest integer that satisfies the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

What about the case of $a=36,b=24,c=12,x=6$?

In this case, the remainder is 0 for x dividing any value, however, the differences amongst a,b, and c are either 12 or 24 where the largest value that divides these is 12 which is c. Thus, x can't always be less than c and this holds.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the second question.

We have 
\begin{align}
a = k q_{1} + r_{1} \\
a = k q_{2} + r_{2} \\
a = k q_{3} + r_{3} \\
\end{align}

Where $a > b > c \geq k$.

Let suppose that $r_{1} = r_{2} = r_{3}$

We get $a - b = k (q_{1} - q_{2})$; $a - c = k (q_{1} - q_{3})$; and $b - c = k (q_{2} - q_{3})$.

We deduce that $k$ is a devider for $(a-b)$, $(a-c)$, and $(b-c)$. And the highest value for $k$ is the H.C.F of these three values.

Let prove now if $k$ is the H.C.F of $(a-b)$, $(a-c)$, and $(b-c)$, we would get $r_{1} = r_{2} = r_{3}$.

We have:

\begin{align}
a - b = k (q_{1} - q_{2}) + (r_{1} - r_{2}) \\
a - c = k (q_{1} - q_{3}) + (r_{2} - r_{3}) \\
b - c = k (q_{2} - q_{3}) + (r_{2} - r_{3}) \\
\end{align}

$k$ is a devider of $(a-b)$, $(a-c)$, and $(b-c)$, so  $r_{1} - r_{2} = r_{2} - r_{3} = r_{1} - r_{3} = 0$ and consequently $r_{1} = r_{2} = r_{3}$